# unable to install Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Interop.Shared.Msi unable to install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SharedFramwork.6.0.6.0.3-servicing.22

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2022

I had problems installing visual studio 2022

an error has occurred

```
unable to install Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Interop.Shared.Msi
unable to install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SharedFramwork.6.0.6.0.3-servicing.22124.1.x64
```

Comment: What's your OS edition? Please make sure all pending windows updates are installed and reboot the computer, check if you have specialized anti-virus or GPO phased permission sofware installed that maybe block this installation, please temproaril disable them and run the vs installer file as adminsitrator to retry. If this issue persists, please share more detailed error message and check if you click 'View log file' or others to locate the root cause of this failed installation.

Comment: I have a Windows Pro,
I don't have any special antivirus installed and there are no pending updates

Comment: Thanks for your update, please go to %temp% folder and check if you can find any log files like 'dd_setup_xxxx_errors', locate the detailed error message about this failed package and share it, that will help us analysis this issue.

Comment: I have three files  https://drive.google.com/file/d/121PQUZi0HZG3p5F-jpghFik6XD0ePPbX/view?usp=sharing   secaind https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oqw0gaZPfiE7M1a1sdYzmiFxiZYLCYbc/view?usp=sharing and last https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OMRgjeB-opYemvZhStdOcsYZsWu9wDRi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, I tried to open the shared files but they are blank. Would you please redirect to the developer community forum and collect, share the whole log files during the installation. Please check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Comment: here are the links https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/PackageId:MicrosoftVisualStudioMinShel/10009305?port=1025&fsid=f44f8b84-e0e7-4e4a-932e-0e91f66fdcb9&entry=problem and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/PackageId:MicrosoftAspNetCoreSharedFra/10009308?port=1026&fsid=ded49636-c4c1-43c5-9d79-9a49002992b7&entry=problem

Comment: Thank you sir, for your help, I just solved the problem

Comment: We are so glad to hear that your issue was solved and thanks for sharing this solution, that will also help other community members in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if in your log file you have

```
Could not register type library for file C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\dte90.olb
```

1. Firstly open CMD or Windows PowerShell as administrator and execute the following command

   ```
   sfc /scannow
   ```

to scan for corruptions in Windows system files and restore corrupted files

2. Then reboot your computer,
3. Disable all antivirus software on your computer, including Windows Defender
4. Reopen VS Installer to repair or retry your VS installation.

it solved my problem